# BeautifulSoup4: how to find a HTML element whose text contains an accented character?

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-unicode

I have this tag in my HTML code

```
<td> Open </td>
```

and another one:

```
<td> Prévu </td>
```

I use (soup is the HTML page)

```
soup.find(text='Open')
```

and it is found but when it comes to use

```
 soup.find(text='Prévu')
```

I get no result (**None** object).

The goal of finding these two keywords is not the search itself but to see whether a specific element in a table has value **Open** and **Prévu** (the table is misformatted, so I can't really rely on a fixed structure to match a specific cell).

I guess the problem comes from the accented letter. I also tried with

```
&egrave;
&eacute;
```

but same result.

Any clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **unicode** to solve the problem:

```
soup.find(text=u'Prévu')
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I just tried but nothing actually changes. also, I'm using BeatifulSoup4 on Python3 which supports only unicode

Comment: Also ensure that your source encoding matches the assumed encoding. For example: Set the encoding of the source file to UTF-8 and set `# coding=UTF-8` in the head of your source files